# Rearrange substrings using two criteria

Tags: java, string, list, sorting, collections

Given a String:

```
a - 11 h - 19 l - 18 d - 19
```

I need to sort its substrings first by numbers (in descending order) and then by letters, so that the result of the sort has the following form:

```
d - 19 h - 19 l - 18 a - 11
```

Comment: Is `a - 11 h - 19 l - 18 d - 19` a single string or are they several strings? Also, what have you tried so far. I don't see any code. If you don't post what you have tried, people will come here and vote to close your question.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow!!  I recommend you take a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Cheers!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @hfontanez it a single string and i need to change it to second variant. Double sorting

Comment: Seems like you need to break the string into substrings that follow a particular pattern. Then, you need to concatenate them back into a single string based in your ordering requirement. For that, you need to write a Comparator. You need to show your work in order to get help in Stack Overflow.

Comment: According to your example output, the *letters are in ascending order* and the *integer numbers are in descending order*. What is the actual sort order required or is that the desired sort order?

Comment: @DevilsHnd this is the desired sort order `d - 19 h - 19 l - 18 a - 11`

Comment: @DevilsHnd based on the desired output, the sort order is sort by the numeric portion in descending order then by the alphabetic portion in ascending order.

Comment: @yurkaishere I edited your post for clarity. Please confirm that this is exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve, the problem must be broken down into subproblems:

1. Break down the input string into substrings
2. Collect each substring into a list
3. Create a comparator that compares the last (numeric) portion of the (sub)string and sorts them in descending order, and then by the beginning portion in ascending order
4. Convert the list of substrings back into a string

### Break down the input string into substrings

```
String regex = "\\w\\s-\\s\\d+";
String input = "a - 11 h - 19 l - 18 d - 19";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
matcher.toMatchResult().groupCount(); // this should return 4 (won't be used in final code)
```

### Collect each substring into a list

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    strings.add(matcher.group());
}
```

The code above will iterate through all of the groups that matched the regex pattern and adds them to a list.

### Create a comparator

```
Comparator<String> compareBySubstring = Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.substring(s.indexOf(" -")))
        .reversed().thenComparing((String s) -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf("-")));
List<String> newList = strings.stream().sorted(compareBySubstring).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The comparator I created compares the last portion of the substrings (after the dash) and sorts them in descending order (`reversed()`). Then, the intermediate result is sorted in ascending order from the beginning of the substring up to the dash. Basically it sorts the intermediate result in alphabetical order since the substrings start with a letter.

### Convert the list of substrings back into a string

```
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        newList.forEach(item -> {
            buffer.append(item + " "); // done to reinsert the space that separated each substring.
        });
```

I created a test program to run this:

```
public class SortBySubstringDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "\\w\\s-\\s\\d+";
        String input = "a - 11 h - 19 l - 18 d - 19";
        System.out.println("Input:\n" + input);

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            strings.add(matcher.group());
        }

        Comparator<String> compareBySubstring = Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.substring(s.indexOf(" -")))
                .reversed().thenComparing((String s) -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf("-")));
        List<String> newList = strings.stream().sorted(compareBySubstring).collect(Collectors.toList());

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        newList.forEach(item -> {
            buffer.append(item + " ");
        });
        String output = buffer.toString().trim();
        System.out.println("Output:\n" + output);
    }
}
```

Which results in the following:

```
Input:
a - 11 h - 19 l - 18 d - 19
Output:
d - 19 h - 19 l - 18 a - 11
```

Comment: @yurkaishere if I truly answered your question, I will appreciate it if you click on the checkmark next to my answer to select it as the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: sorry i'm newbie on this site, but i have done this :)

Answer (score 2):

One alternative for your specific example is to use `stream`:

1. Replace `" - "` with `" "` to obtain a string with letters and numbers separated by whitespace.
2. Split using `" "` to obtain an `array` with letters in even indexes and numbers in odd indexes.
3. Create an `IntStream` with even indexes and map them to a `Map.Entry<String,Integer>` using `array[index]` as key and `array[index + 1]` as value.
4. Sort the `stream` with a comparator that compares values first and then keys.
5. Map the entry `stream` to a string with `key + " - " + value`.
6. Finally, collect the `stream` to a string using `Collectors.joining(" ")` to separate each `"letter - number"` with a whitespace.

Summarizing all in a method:

```
public static String sort(String str) {

    String[] arr = str.replaceAll(" - ", " ").split(" ");

    Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> comparator = Comparator
        .comparingInt(Map.Entry<String, Integer>::getValue).reversed()
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey);
    
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(arr[i], Integer.parseInt(arr[i + 1])))
        .sorted(comparator).map(entry -> entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

Test:

```
String str = "a - 11 h - 19 l - 18 d - 19";

String strSorted = sort(str);

System.out.println(strSorted);
```

Output:

```
d - 19 h - 19 l - 18 a - 11
```

Comment: What happens with your solution if there is more than one letter that repeats? For example, what if the input string is something like this: `a - 11 h - 19 l - 18 d - 19 a - 10`? I don't think this solution works as good because you are assuming the letters won't repeat. There is nothing in the post (other than the string not having duplicate letters) that state this is always going to be the case. The worst part is that you are not even explaining your assumptions.

Comment: @hfontanez what's wrong with this solution when one letter repeats? The output using the example in your comment is: `d - 19 h - 19 l - 18 a - 11 a - 10`. What should be the output?

Comment: I stand corrected. I must've done something wrong when I copy and pasted your solution.  That said, you should explain your answer in a bit more detail. This is almost a "code-only" answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'll work on the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "a - 11 h - 19 l - 18 d - 19";

record Pair(String string, int number) { }
System.out.println( new Scanner( s ).findAll( "(\\w)\\s-\\s(\\d+)" )
                        .map( matchResult -> new Pair( matchResult.group( 1 ), Integer.parseInt( matchResult.group( 2 ) ) ) )
                        .sorted( Comparator.<Pair>comparingInt( Pair::number ).reversed().thenComparing( Pair::string ) )
                        .map( pair -> pair.string() + " - " + pair.number() )
                        .collect( Collectors.joining( " " ) ) );
```

Comment: "code-only" answers are frowned upon. Please explain your proposed solution.